# How to convert webp animation to gif animation with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How to convert webp animation to gif animation. i do like this: `ffmpeg -i My_anim.webp animation.gif`

error `[webp @ 000001b7db7b5b80] image data not found [vist#0:0/webp @ 000001b7db7aef80] Decoding error: Invalid data found when processing input Cannot determine format of input stream 0:0 after EOF Error marking filters as finished`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `ffmpeg` just doesn't seem to have good decoding support for animated ***WebP***. See an old (but not yet done) enhancement request here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4907.

If you're not tied to `ffmpeg` you can try using [***ImageMagick***](https://imagemagick.org/) which is able to do this conversion. Use something like:

```
magick convert -format gif My_anim.webp animation.gif
```

Or:

```
magick mogrify -format gif My_anim.webp
```

Comment: Thank you so much!